# winpexpect: winspawn is blocking

Tags: python, expect

I am trying to use winpexpect to have an interactive subprocesses in Python.  I am completely baffled.  When I run a unit test, winspawn executes normally along with all the expects.  When I run my program as a whole, winspawn inexplicably blocks forever.  How can this be?  As far as I know, winspawn is non-blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out that the string I was passing to winpexpect was Unicode in one case and str in another case.  It seems that winpexpect will block at winspawn if the string you pass in is unicode.